# Script crashing with ETIMEDOUT

Tags: node.js

I have a nodejs script continuosly running on server which makes couple of http request simultaneously.
But at times the script crashes with error ETIMEDOUT. How can I catch this error as it doesnt says on which http call the error occurred.

I am also using try/catch block but still the script crashes.

How can I make sure the script runs continuosly despite of this error.

Any pointers on this will be helpful.

Comment: Can you show some code?

Comment: Try/catch won't work for async calls. Check the `err` value in request callback.

Answer (score 0):

`ETIMEDOUT` happens only to connect. This can happen if the connection attempt is not successful within a system-dependent amount of time.

You can use a both `cluster` with `domain` to handle the use case of running even when after the crash (have a new process start).

Here is an example: https://nodejs.org/api/domain.html